# How to highlight the selected item in linear layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, background

I am having `linear layout`, in which it has one `imageview` and one `textview`, when i touch the `linear layout`, it should highlight the image as well as text inside the linear layout with different color. I have tried using set background for the linear layout when it is pressed since i have used `ontouch-listener` it doesn't shows the color even i tried to change the colors programmatically but it didn't works.

Can anyone tell me how i can change the `imageview` and `textview` color when a linear layout is touched.

```
Xml:



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_otherexpense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/linearlayout_check"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_otherexpense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@mipmap/expense"
            android:tint="#6666FF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_otherexpense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/dayexpense"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Selector:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />
```

Code:

```
    li_otherexpense.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            startActivity(new Intent(NewDaybook_Activity.this,     AddingNewExpense.class));
            NewDaybook_Activity.this.finish();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. this is working fine for me .May be it will helpfull

```
findViewById(R.id.linear_otherexpense).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        // When you Touch Down 
                        // U can change Text and Image As per your Functionality  

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        //When you Release the touch 
                        // U can change Text and Image As per your Functionality

                        break;
                }


                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_otherexpense);
         imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_otherexpense);
        linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                return true;
            }
        });
```